# Determining if a power set is one to one or onto.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $P$ be the power set of $\{a,b,c\}$. A function $f: P \to \mathbb{Z}$; the set of integers, follows: For $A$ in $P$, $f(A)=$the number of elements in $A$.

1. Is $f$ one-to-one? Explain.
2. Is $f$ onto? Explain.

I'm not sure how to picture this function. I understand how to expand the power set of $\{a,b,c\}$ to get $\{a,b,c\}=\{∅,a,b,c,(a,b),(b,c),(c,a),(a,b,c)\}$ and I also understand what a one-to-one function is and an onto function is, but I'm confused as to what the function the problem is trying to elude to and the wording of the problem seems odd to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In your example you have various subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$ of cardinality $1$ and $2$. You are mapping members of $P$ to $Z$ using the cardinality of each member, by example $\{a,c\}\mapsto |\{a,c\}|=2$

Comment: So you are supposed to map the cardinality of each of the subsets within the power set to the set of integers? 

How did you know to use the cardinality?

Thanks for your help Masacroso.

Comment: Your first mistake is trying to picture the function. Don't. Use the definitions and work with them. After you've done that for a while, you'll develop a picture of your own, which will be far more accurate than anything anyone could try and explain to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: To answer "How did you know to use the cardinality?" By reading the definition of $f$ in the question: $f(A)=$ the number of elements in $A$.

Comment: That sort of makes sense now but how come it couldn't be interpreted as the number of unique elements within the powerset? As in, the number of subsets within the powerset, which is 8 in this example. Why does it refer to the cardinality of each of the subsets within the powerset?

Comment: It says $f(A)$ is the number of elements in $A$, not the number of elements in the power set of $A$ or in any other power set.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys thanks for the help, I think I figured out the answer thanks to you guys.

If I'm understanding correctly the power set of {abc} will map to an integer based on the cardinality of each of the subsets thus

{null set} maps to 0, {a} maps to 1, {b} maps to 1, (a,b} maps to 2, {a,b,c} maps to 3 and so forth.

Thus we have more than one x value mapping the same y value,{a} and {b} both map to 1 so it is not a one to one function.

Furthermore, if this function is to map to the set of all integers, all of the integers are not covered as we only use 0,1,2 and 3. Therefore it is not onto either.

Hope that helps anyone who needs assistance on this question in the future.

Let me know if I made any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Well,f is clearly not one to one. A function  f:$A\rightarrow B$ is one to one if for every a,b $\in$ A, f(a)= f(b) iff a=b. Since f((a,b) = f((b,c))=f((c,a)) =2.

Is f onto? Well,consider the definition: A function f:$A\rightarrow B$ is onto B if for every b in B, there exists an a in A such that b = f(a). Is this true in this case? Why or why not?